# Why my modifications have no effects on Symfony website?

Tags: symfony, drop-down-menu, twig

I'm in charge of the administration of website build on Symfony but i'm not very familiar with this framework.
They want me to delete the Deutsch part. My first move was to delete the Deutsch link in the languages dropdown menu.
But even if in the source code the link is now gone, it keeps displaying on the website what am I missing ?

```
<a href="#" class="idioma" data-toggle="dropdown">{% trans %}Language{% endtrans %}</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <li><a href="{{ path('valessentia_frontend_homepage_culture', { _locale: 'en' }) }}">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('valessentia_frontend_homepage_culture', { _locale: 'fr' }) }}">Français</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('valessentia_frontend_homepage_culture', { _locale: 'it' }) }}">Italiano</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('valessentia_frontend_homepage_culture', { _locale: 'es' }) }}">Español</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the website: http://valessentia.com/fr

Comment: did you clear the cache?  app/console cache:clear --env=prod

Comment: i don't have it on local i was working directly on the distant server.

Comment: Do you have a ssh connection?

Comment: No i don't. Could it be the solution? Is it impossible to just delete a line of the code via Filezilla or something?

Comment: you could rename the directory app/cache/prod then symfony2 should generate a new one, and then you could remove the old one

Comment: Thanks for the tip it worked. I'll try to work with that solution for now.

Comment: You should setup a correct [development environment](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html).

Comment: Yeah i know but it's an emergency i'm not event formed to Symfony.